# Prevent Propagation - OnTouch Select - Material React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am working with **ReactJS** and the library **@material-ui/core**.

I want to prevent the event propagation on Click, this is my code:

```
<NumPad.Number 
    onChange={val => { this.setPrice(val) } }>
    <TextField
        label={needsUnits ? "Precio Unitario" : "Precio"}
        id="simple-start-adornment"
        placeholder="20.00"
        InputProps={{
            startAdornment: 
                <InputAdornment position="start">
                    {this.state.params.businessCurrency === 3 &&
                    <Select value={this.state.service.currency} 
                        name="currency" id="currency"
                        style={{zIndex: 1000}}
                        onChange={(event) => this.setState({ service: { ...this.state.service, currency: event.target.value } })}
                        inputProps={{ name: 'age', id: 'age-simple', }}>
                        <MenuItem value={1}>Bs. </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value={2}>USD </MenuItem>
                    </Select>}
                    {this.state.params.businessCurrency !== 3 &&
                        getCurrencyAbbreviation(this.state.params.businessCurrency) }
                </InputAdornment>,
        }}
        value={this.state.service.price}
    />
</NumPad.Number>
```

When the select is opened the event continue with the TextField, but I only want to open the list in the Select component.

Comment: A working [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces the problem would be helpful in making it easier/quicker for someone to experiment with and verify potential solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem including the event onClick and managing the event.

```
<Select value={this.state.service.currency} 
    name="currency" id="currency"
    onChange={(event) => this.setState({ service: { ...this.state.service, currency: event.target.value } })}
    onClick={this.preventPropagation}
    inputProps={{ name: 'age', id: 'age-simple', }}>
    <MenuItem value={1}>Bs. </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={2}>USD </MenuItem>
</Select>
```

And the event must stop the propagation.

```
preventPropagation(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Also I didn't need to add zIndex in the styles.